# ReactJS How do i call setState nested Functions

Tags: reactjs

Lets say that i have this component:

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      test: false
    };
  }

  func1 = () => {
    function update() {
      this.setState({ test: true }); // not working
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

As you see i have func1 which is in arrow form,and there is another function update in `function update()` form

So how do i call setState from inside function update as seen in example ?

EDIT:
the reason why i am trying to do something like this is i am using a game engine inside react component called phaser.So actually if i make update function as an arrow function for some reason phaser cant understand it and throws undefined error.update function is called 60 times in second

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          test: false
        };
      }
componentDidMount(){
this.func1()
}

      func1 = () => {
     var  game = new Phaser.Game(canvas_width,canvas_height,Phaser.AUTO,'gameDiv',{ preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

        function update() {
          this.setState({ test: true }); // not working
        }
      };

      render() {
        return <div />;
      }
    }
```

SECOND EDIT:
THANKS GUYS WRITING update = update.bind(this)   before var game solved it

Comment: I can't understand how you use `update` function here? You are not invoking it also not returning from `funct1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an arrow function again:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      test: false

    };
  }

  func1 = () => {

    const update = () => {
      this.setState({ test: true }) // not working
    }
    return update;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.func1()();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state);
    return (
      <div></div>
    )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

When you use a regular function you lose the scope of `this`. When you use an arrow function you can use it without worrying about `this` as you do in your first function. But, instead of an arrow function that would work:

```
func1 = () => {
    const that = this;
    return function update() {
      that.setState({ test: true }); // not working
    }
}
```

Or even with `bind` as @Tholle suggested in his comment:

```
func1 = () => {
    return ( function update() {
      this.setState({ test: true }); // not working
    }).bind(this);
}
```

Furthermore, you can define them separately and call the `update` function inside the func1.

```
func1 = () => {
    this.update();
};

update() {
  this.setState({ test: true }); // not working
}
```

This works too, because you are auto-binding your `func1` function to `this` and your `update` function is invoked from there, keepin `this` scope.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass `this` in as an argument, perhaps calling it `self` within the function. I.e `self.setState`. You could also `bind` or `call` the function passing the `this` as an argument. The important thing is that `this` still references the correct React component.

also, I'm a little confused why you're defining a function which returns a function like that. Could you just pass the function in point free form instead and not need to worry about this issue? You still need to bind the function to `this`..

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.func1 = this.func1.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      test: false
    };
  }

  func1() {
    this.setState({ test: true });
  };

  render() {
    return <div callback={this.func1} />;
  }
}
```